# How Can a JAR File Delete Itself?

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, kill-process, taskkill

I need a JAR file to delete itself.

The issue is that Windows locks the JAR file while it is running, and can't delete itself directly.

I have looked into solutions where a batch script could kill the JAR process and then delete the file, but

- `System.exit(0)` is not desired because it is not runnable via `Batch` file.
- `taskkill /F /IM "java.exe"` is not desired because it kills **ALL** `Java` processes.
- `jps` cannot be used [because it is only available in the `JDK`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825197/does-jre-has-diagnostics-tools) and users might run a `JRE` so that would fail.

---

I'm stuck on looking for a solution which lets me find the `PID` of the current `JAR` using `Java` code, then writing out a `Batch` command and inserting the `PID` which kills the process e.g. like the following:

```
printWriter.println("taskkill /PID " + currentJARPID);
```

If you're wondering what this is for, you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47017455/3764804) answer.

Comment: Can the java file read the bat file output, waiting for a kill command?  Or must you kill the file from the bat file, without interacting with the java file?

Comment: @phflack: I have to kill the `Java` process from the batch file so that the `JAR` is no longer locked and can be deleted. Deleting cannot be done from within the `Java` code since it cannot run and delete itself at the same time due to file locking on `Windows`.

Comment: I understand that, I will rephrase the question: can the java process read the .bat output

Comment: Also related [How can a Java program get its own process ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35842/5475891)

Comment: Does the process you are considering actually work reliably at all? Presumably it will work if the JVM shuts down -- the lock on the executable is released -- more quickly than the batch file can be loaded and executed. I concede that things might work this way, but I don't see how it can be guaranteed. Could you not launch the JVM from a batch file, and then have that batch file delete the JAR once the JVM has exited?

Comment: @KevinBoone: The JAR is started normally via double-click and at any time the code may decide to self-destruct the JAR. The current strategy works because when the process is killed, the lock is already released before the JAR is attempted to be deleted. If this order is not ensured, one may just loop in the batch file and check if the file still exists, then try to delete and repeat till it succeeded. Finally, the batch file can delete itself to clean up since there is no lock on the batch file when it executes.

Comment: "the code may decide to self-destruct the JAR" - can this code be in the JAR itself, or must it be in the bat script?

Comment: @phflack: In the bat script because Java cannot delete its own `JAR` executable while it's running. I just need the `taskkill` by `PID` of the running `JAR` part via batch.

Comment: I highly suspect this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), what is your overall goal? If you're just trying to delete the jar file, it's very different from requiring the bat file to kill the jar process

Comment: @phflack: No. I just want the `JAR` to be able to delete itself and it can't be done while it's running due to file locking so calling a batch script to do it is the best idea since the `JAR` locking only happens on `Windows`. Therefore, there is no way to do this in `Java` code.

Comment: You just denied that this is an XY problem, then explained how this is an XY problem

Comment: @phflack: I don't care what it is, can you please just help solve the question like you should when commenting? I'm just looking for some proper implementation of this functionality. You provided no suggestions or alternatives whatsoever besides some pointless XY problem claims. My actual problem is **deleting a JAR file by itself** and the attempted solution is **using a batch file** because there is no better way. I already made this very clear I thought.

Comment: You did not make your intentions clear.  This is what an XY problem is, you ask for something difficult when there are easier solutions.  You asked for a batch command that will kill a specific process, and how to get the process ID from within java.  What you want is for your JAR to delete itself.  These are two different problems, and prevented me from answering the real question you have

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working example

```
public class Delete
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable
    {
        System.out.println("Running");

        System.out.println("Deleting");
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c ping localhost -n 6 > nul && del Delete.jar");

        System.out.println("Ending");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

The main feature powering this is `cmd /c ping localhost -n 6 > nul && del Delete.jar`

It deletes the jar file after [waiting 5 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1672349/5475891)

To test, I used `javac Delete.java && jar cfe Delete.jar Delete Delete.class` to build the jar, and `java -jar Delete.jar` to run

I also verified that I could not delete the jar file while it was executing, through `new File("Delete.jar").delete();` and also using Windows Explorer

Comment: Also note that .class files do not have the Windows locking issue, and using `new File("Delete.class");` works

Comment: You can even use `-n 2` and it will still work fine but delete faster